# Need to get the second list ordering when validating the content between 2 different lists by using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a use case where I have all the Employee data in a list (`List<Employee> employeesList`) and I would like to get the required employees by providing another list of employee ID's (`List<String> employeeIdList`) I need the same order of `employeeIdList` for the employees after retrieval.

I am able to achieve this with the regular nested for loop, but I would like to check what's the best way to achieve it using Java streams.

By using the regular streams, I am not getting the right order, so I tried to check a condition during the iteration and added to a different list, but I still have to collect the objects which I am really not using them anywhere.

Is there any other best option to achieve this functionality. Any help is appreciated.

Below is the sample code.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * The Class SimpleClass.
 */
public class SimpleClass {

    /**
     * The main method.
     *
     * @param args the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee employee1 = new Employee("1", "Employee 1");
        Employee employee2 = new Employee("2", "Employee 2");
        Employee employee3 = new Employee("3", "Employee 3");
        Employee employee4 = new Employee("4", "Employee 4");
        Employee employee5 = new Employee("5", "Employee 5");
        List<Employee> employeesList = new LinkedList<>();
        employeesList.add(employee5);
        employeesList.add(employee1);
        employeesList.add(employee2);
        employeesList.add(employee3);
        employeesList.add(employee4);

        List<String> neededEmployees = new LinkedList<>();

        neededEmployees.add("4");
        neededEmployees.add("1");
        neededEmployees.add("5");

        /* Nested For Loop */
        List<Employee> requiredEmployeesList = new LinkedList<>();
        for (String employeeId : neededEmployees) {
            for (Employee employee : employeesList) {
                if (employee.getId().equals(employeeId)) {
                    requiredEmployeesList.add(employee);
                }
            }
        }
        printEmployeeDetails(requiredEmployeesList);

        /* Using Streams - Not returning the required order */
        List<Employee> employeesListNew = employeesList.stream().filter(
                employee -> neededEmployees.stream().anyMatch(employeeId -> employeeId.equals(employee.getId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        printEmployeeDetails(employeesListNew);

        /* Using Streams - adding to a different list based on condition - This provides the right order as required*/
        List<Employee> sortedEmployeesList = new ArrayList<>();
        neededEmployees.stream()
                .filter(employeeId -> employeesList.stream()
                        .anyMatch(employee -> employee.getId().equals(employeeId) ? sortedEmployeesList.add(employee) : false))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        printEmployeeDetails(sortedEmployeesList);
    }

    /**
     * Prints the employee details.
     *
     * @param employeesList the employees list
     */
    private static void printEmployeeDetails(List<Employee> employeesList) {
        System.out.println("Printing Employees List");
        for (Employee employee : employeesList) {
            System.out.println(employee.getId());
            System.out.println(employee.getName());
        }
    }

}

class Employee {
    String id;
    String name;
    // Setter, Getter and AllArgsConstructor
}
```

Comment: your first loop and stream are not equivalent, are they? and stop using a `LinkedList`

Comment: @Eugene, all 3 options provided are similar, first one is using nested for loop which works fine, second one is similar but adding items are different which is why its not working, third option also works fine with Stream, so looking for best options. There might be a chance that the values are not properly ordered if i don't use LinkedList as it can be dynamically added from different places, this is a sample code. I initially used ArrayList, also tried with LinkedList but no luck.

Comment: you did not get my comment, you loop and the first stream are _not_ equivalent; order of lists is different. What is the first list in your for loop and the first one in the stream?

Comment: A condition like `a? b: false` is just `a && b`. But when b is an `add` to a list within a predicate while you’re collecting into another list that you are dropping afterwards, you should yourself ask what the … you are doing. When you do `firstList.filter(predicate based on second)`, the order will be the order of `firstList`, whereas with `secondList.filter(predicate based on first)`, the order will be the order of `secondList`. It’s as simple as that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the ways to do what you're looking for without sorting the actual data would be using a map of id to an employee itself such as:

```
Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = employeesList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Function.identity()));
```

and then mapping them *iterating in the order based on the `neededEmployees`* as follows:

```
List<Employee> requiredAndSortedEmployeesList = neededEmployees.stream()
        .map(employeeMap::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Using a map is a recommended optimization, but the crucial point should be mentioned: by iterating over `neededEmployees` in the second operation, we get the result in the order of `neededEmployees`. The OP’s inefficient approach could have been fixed in a similar way, by streaming over `neededEmployees` and using `employeesList` in an intermediate operation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `filter` and `sort` operation for your scenario.

for sort you should implement custom `comparator` based on `neededEmployees` items index.

```
Comparator<Employee> comparator=Comparator.comparingInt(o -> neededEmployees.indexOf(o.id));
```

in fact this comparator act based on employeeId index in the `neededEmployees` list.

then use `filter`  to filter your list based on `neededEmployees` after that sort it by 
custom comparator. although this comparator dose not have good performance for huge list but since the size of `neededEmployees` list is not huge actually it dose not have bottleneck in this case.

same reason for filter is correct. you can use `Set` instead of `List` but here is not important since it size is little.

```
sortedEmployeesList = employeesList.stream()
          .filter(employee -> neededEmployees.contains(employee.id))
          .sorted(comparator)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> [Employee{id='4', name='Employee 4'}, 
>     Employee{id='1', name='Employee 1'}, 
>     Employee{id='5', name='Employee 5'}]

Comment: Overcomplicated for this simple task.

Comment: …and horribly inefficient with all those linear searches.

Comment: @Holger, I'm completely aware about it complicity but I supposed the  `neededEmployees` list has small size.

Answer (score 1):

your first stream attempt goes in employee order not needed employee order
basically use your first one but reverse the lists, like the second but that one makes a list and then just throws it away. and then adds it to another list.just do this :)

```
List<Employee> newList = neededEmployees.stream()
             .map(eid-> employeesList.stream().filter(employee -> 
                       employee.getId().equals(eid)).findAny().get())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: mavriksc, thank you for the response. when we iterate the id's list the return type will be List<String> as I need the employee objects, this will not work

Comment: Thank you Mavriksc

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

It consists of the following two steps

> **1-Filter employeeList with neededEmployees**
>
> - returns a list of list of employee. (`List<List<Employee>`)

It means

{ {employee4 } , {{employee1}} , {employee5} }

---

> **2- Use flatMap to flat previous list**

it means

**convert**
{ {employee4 } , {{employee1}} , {employee5} } **to** {employee4,employee1,employee5}

---

> **I coded aforementioned scenario as follows**

```
List<Employee> result = neededEmployees.stream().
                map(neededEmployee -> employeesList.stream().
                        filter(employee -> employee.getId().equals(neededEmployee))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> **Print Results**

```
result.forEach(

    employee -> System.out.println(employee.getName())

);
```

**Employee 4**

**Employee 1**

**Employee 5**

Comment: Thank you for the quick Mehrdad, the output does not match the order as my employee ID list, I need the employee objects in the same order as the list i have added in my employeeIdList. The output should be Employee4, Employee1, Employee 5

Comment: Oh sorry for misunderstanding, I'll fix it right now

Answer (score 0):

```
    neededEmployees.forEach(eid->employeesList.forEach(emp->{
        if(eid.equalsIgnoreCase(emp.getId())) {
            requiredEmployeesList.add(emp);
        }
    }));

    requiredEmployeesList.forEach(re->System.out.println(re.getId()));
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I am looking for options using streams, Regular nested forloop is already present in the sample I shared.